# Edit text value duplicates in list view while scrolling

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

I am new to android. when I was inserting value to the edit text in the list view it gets duplicates while scrolling. I searched everywhere but i could n't find exact solution. my list view is very large because it fetches value from database.
here is my android code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.orders);
    list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list1);
     this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

    SelectItems();
    ViewItems();        
     cases = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.cases);
      pcs = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.pcs);
    clear1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.clear2);
    cout1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.cout2);

    clear1.setOnClickListener(this);
    cout1.setOnClickListener(this);

}

private void SelectItems() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {

           datas = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this.getApplicationContext());
        newDB = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor c = newDB.rawQuery("select distinct im_code ,im_desc ,im_srp "
                + " from itemmaster", null);

        Log.v("item detailss", c.toString());

            while (c.moveToNext()){

            HashMap<String, String> datanums = new HashMap<String, String>();
            String im_code = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("im_code"));

             String desc = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("im_desc"));

             datanums.put("code", im_code);
             datanums.put("name", desc);
                       String price = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("im_srp"));
            datanums.put("ims", price);

            datas.add(datanums);

            }
        } catch (SQLiteException se ) {
            Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Could not create or Open the database");
           } 

}

private void ViewItems() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    list.setAdapter(null);
    String[] fromwhere = { "code","name","ims" };
    int[] viewswhere = { R.id.code,R.id.name,R.id.srp};

          ADAhere = new SimpleAdapter(Orders.this, datas,
            R.layout.order_simple_row, fromwhere, viewswhere);
    list.setAdapter(ADAhere);
    }



@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.clear2:
           Intent i= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Orders.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;  

        case R.id.cout2:
              Checkout(v);

                break;

        default:
            break;
        }

}
private void Checkout(View view) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
     AlertDialog.Builder alertDialou = new AlertDialog.Builder(Orders.this);
     alertDialou.setMessage("DO YOU WANT TO CHECKOUT ?");


     alertDialou.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            getcases();
            invoiceAlert();


        }


        private void invoiceAlert() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialo = new AlertDialog.Builder(Orders.this);
             alertDialo.setMessage("ORDER SUCCESS..");
             alertDialo.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    //Orderheader();
                    printAlert();
                }



                private void printAlert() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    AlertDialog.Builder alertDial = new AlertDialog.Builder(Orders.this);
                     alertDial.setMessage("DO YOU WANT TO PRINT NOW ?");
                     alertDial.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            Intent in = new Intent(Orders.this,Menu_iem.class);

                            startActivity(in);
                        }
                    });
                     alertDial.setNegativeButton("LATER", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
                     AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDial.create();

                      // show alert

                      alertDialog.show();
                }
            });
             AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialo.create();

              // show alert

              alertDialog.show();
        }

    });

 alertDialou.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

   @Override
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent in= new Intent(Orders.this,Orders.class);
    startActivity(in);
    }
 });         
 AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialou.create();

// show alert

 alertDialog.show();    
 }

  protected void getcases() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
 DatabaseHelper databasecontroller = new DatabaseHelper(Orders.this);
List<Map<String, String>> data = null;
data = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
float srps = (float) 0.0;
int qtys = 0;
databas.put("imuom", "CASES");


 if(list != null){

        for(int i = 0; i< list.getChildCount();i++){

            View vie = list.getChildAt(i);

            EditText ed1= (EditText) vie.findViewById(R.id.cases);
                String cases1 = ed1.getText().toString();

                databas.put("A",ed1.getText().toString());

      EditText ed2= (EditText) vie.findViewById(R.id.piece);
                String cases2 = ed2.getText().toString();

                databas.put("B",ed1.getText().toString());    
 data.add(databas);
 databasecontroller.inserttable(databas);
   }
   }
```

please help me with this.

Comment: where are you showing data in editText show some code

Comment: list view is maid with three text view and 2 edit texts. using the above code i just added data to the text view. and in the edit text  i want to enter and save data to database on a button click

Comment: @ellie, when you say editText value gets duplicated, are you trying to say the say value appears in different editText of some another item in the Listview ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set tag in your getview method of adapter class and also post your code for adapter class ,so we can help better.

```
if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.simple_store_item, parent, false);
            mViewHolder = new CustomViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);
        } else {
            mViewHolder = (CustomViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
```

Comment: You will have to make your own custom adapter instead of using SimpleAdapter if you want to customize your UI. It will be a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

Add this two methods to your listview adapter class

```
@Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public int getViewTypeCount() {
            return getCount();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Listview in Android reuse items, so if user scrolls view, some view reuse old views and it should show duplicate value if you don't manage careful.
If your row views have alot items, you should check conditions to show view properly. Example:

```
if(true){
    edt.setText("abc");
}else{
    edt.setText("cde");
}
```

If you show data in each condition, you must set value or reset that view in case unuse